# Как вывести размер файла?

Tags: php

Подскажите как вывести размер файла в `php`, чтобы напротив имени файла выводился размер (например: `index.php - 10 kb.`, `functions.php - 25 kb.`) может какую-то функцию подскажете, через которую можно, выводить размер файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть много функций, вот одна из них. Вставляешь в `get_filesize ()` название своего `php` файла, а на выходе получаешь размер. Также этой функцией можно, получить размер и других файлов.

```
function get_filesize($file)
{
    if(!file_exists($file)) return "Файл  не найден";

  $filesize = filesize($file);

if($filesize > 1024){
$filesize = ($filesize/1024);
    if($filesize > 1024){
    $filesize = ($filesize/1024);
        if($filesize > 1024) {
        $filesize = ($filesize/1024);
        $filesize = round($filesize, 1);
        return $filesize." ГБ";       
        } else {
        $filesize = round($filesize, 1);
        return $filesize." MБ";   
        }       
    } else {
    $filesize = round($filesize, 1);
    return $filesize." Кб";   
    }  
    } else {
    $filesize = round($filesize, 1);
    return $filesize." байт";   
    }
}
```

Применение:

```
$size = get_filesize ('functions.php'); 

echo "Размер файла: <strong>".$size."</strong>";
```

Answer (score 7):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
function formatFileSize($size) {
    $a = array("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB");
    $pos = 0;
    while ($size >= 1024) {
        $size /= 1024;
        $pos++;
    }
    return round($size,2)." ".$a[$pos];
}
```